# Where should I put "serviceAccountCredentials.json" for Firebase Admin, at production?

Tags: firebase, nuxtjs3

in development,
I make a config directory and I put the json file in this directory.

```
>> .env
FIREBASE_ADMINSDK_PATH=./config/firebase-adminsdk-2222222.json

>> test.ts
import { initializeApp, getApps, cert } from 'firebase-admin/app'
const apps = getApps()
if (!apps.length) {
    initializeApp({
        credential: cert(config.FIREBASE_ADMINSDK_PATH)),
    })
}
...
```

But in production environment, there is only 2 directory in '.output' directory (.output/public, .output/server) So nuxt can not find "./config/firebase-adminsdk-2222222.json" file.

Where should I put "serviceAccountCredentials.json" for Firebase Admin, at production?

Comment: What service are you hosting your app on? If its a Google Cloud service, you could use the application default credentials and not worry about the service-account file

Comment: It's for firestore. ADC(application default credentials) is little bit difficult for me. Please Let me know adout the service-account file.

Comment: What cloud provider are you using for hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than providing the file location of the service account, you can provide the service account [in line as done in this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.credential_n.md#example_2). Reading the `service-account.json` file should give you enough details to fill in the initialization. Copying the initialization here as well:

```js
// Providing a service account object inline
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<KEY>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

**NOTE:** It is advisable to [use attached service accounts when possible](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-service-accounts#use-attached-service-accounts) and encouraged to use the application default credential in most cases.